# Upgrade/Replacement options for Cannondale Headshok DD50?

Tags: repair, fork, suspension, replacement, cannondale

I have an older Cannondale that I love.

It's an F600 comp (the special edition one in pumpkin orange), with a DD50 front shock.

The problem is that the DD50 is WORN as all heck. Even when locked out, it has "give" to it and makes noises that just worry me...

I ride the bike every day and the worn shock is not a deal breaker - but it sure is annoying.

From what I read, getting an old (1996?) Headshok serviced is next to impossible - and quite expensive.

So I'm looking at options and suggestions. Here are a couple options I've come up with so far :

1. Get a headset adapter and use a 1 1/8" rigid fork.
2. Get a headset adapter and find a cheap 1 1/8" suspension fork.
3. I've found a cheap ($100) RST Deuce fork on eBay (1.5")...that seems like it would be pretty much a bolt-on deal. Other than the fact that it I think the axle would be too large to fit my existing front hub.

What do you guys/gals think? What would you recommend? What are the pros and cons of each option?

If it matters - this is my daily commuter/fun bike.

Comment: Found http://shockspital.com/this site and thought of your question

Comment: Awesome, thanks @mikes, I'm gonna shoot them an email and see what's up. Love the domain name too haha!

Answer (score 1):

"Product Information -- Our Cannondale elastomer kit will make your Head Shox work like new." $42.  http://www.suspensionforkparts.net/eshop/index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=156